# Retrofit json data show

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I have some `Json` data and i want to receive `Json` data using `Retrofit` and i want to show in my `RecyclerView`.

This is my `Pojo` Class

```
public class Movie implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("title")
public String title;
@SerializedName("movie_name")
public String movieName;
@SerializedName("link")
public String link;

protected Movie(Parcel in) {
    title = in.readString();
    movieName = in.readString();
    link = in.readString();
}



public Movie(String title , String movieName , String link){
    this.title = title;
    this.movieName = movieName;
    this.link = link;
}

public static final Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Creator<Movie>() {
    @Override
    public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Movie(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Movie[size];
    }
};

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public String getMovieName() {
    return movieName;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public void setMovieName(String movieName) {
    this.movieName = movieName;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeString(movieName);
    dest.writeString(link);
}
}
```

And this is my response class.

```
public class Movies {


@SerializedName("results")
private ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<Movie> getMovies() {
    return movies;
}
}
```

My Api Interface class

```
public interface ApiInterFace {

@GET("sort_by")
Call<Movies> discoverSongList(@Path("sort_by") String sort_by);

}
```

My Fetch Data class

```
public class FetchSongList extends AsyncTask<String , Void , List<Movie>>{


public static final String TAG_NAME = FetchSongList.class.getSimpleName();


public Lisener lisener;

public FetchSongList(Lisener lisener){
    this.lisener = lisener;
}

@Override
protected List<Movie> doInBackground(String... params) {

    if (params.length==0){
        return null;
    }

    String name = params[0];

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://banglahdnatok.com/Hindi%20Movie%20Songs/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    ApiInterFace apiInterFace = retrofit.create(ApiInterFace.class);
    Call<Movies> call = apiInterFace.discoverSongList(name);
    try{
        Response<Movies> response = call.execute();
        Movies movies = response.body();
        return movies.getMovies();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> movies) {
    super.onPostExecute(movies);
    if (movies!=null){
        lisener.onFetchLisener(movies);
    }
    else {
        lisener.onFetchLisener(new ArrayList<Movie>());
    }
}

public interface Lisener{
    void onFetchLisener(List<Movie> movies);
}


}
```

This is my MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FetchSongList.Lisener{
public RecyclerView recyclerView;

public MyRecycleViewAdapter adapter;
public ArrayList<Movie> movieArrayList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    fetch("just_added");
    adapter = new MyRecycleViewAdapter(this , movieArrayList);

}


public void fetch(String name){

    FetchSongList fetchSongList = new FetchSongList(this);
    fetchSongList.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, name);
}


@Override
public void onFetchLisener(List<Movie> movies) {

    adapter.add(movieArrayList);
}
}
```

When i run my application it shows some error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while  executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL "sort_by" does not contain "{sort_by}". (parameter #1)
```

How i can solve this issue?

Comment: Please do not post the whole project. read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry except this i have nothing to do.
again sorry for this. @Vucko

Comment: I don't see the need for the `Movies` class at all. You should just have a `Call<List<Movie>>`

Comment: Half the code here in obsolete. DO not make us read hundreds of lines of code. Be smart!

Comment: @Vucko i think he just posted relevant part of code

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing new AsyncTask every-time you can run this on main thread, Retrofit itself runs the network call on background thread.
Here is sample code :

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://banglahdnatok.com/Hindi%20Movie%20Songs/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    ApiInterFace apiInterFace = retrofit.create(ApiInterFace.class);
    Call<Movies> call = apiInterFace.discoverSongList(name);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Movies>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<Movies> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                //This block runs on main thread
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                //This block runs on main thread
            }
        });
}
```

Hope it will fix the problem.

Comment: full url is http://banglahdnatok.com/Hindi%20Movie%20Songs/just_added

so i think space doesn't problem.
url works fine. @Neo

Comment: Updated my solution, kindly check :)

Comment: I have tried it it works for me. Just thinking learning new things that's it.
By the way thnx for your answer. @Neo

Comment: @user3102913 did you find any solution for your issue ?

Comment: @Neo i think too, but i must see something if he didnt find solution , also nice anwer :)

Comment: @Yasin, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Neo this is not my question my friend ^^